# How to perform element-wise mutliply on these two?

Tags: numpy

I tried with np.multiplty but it gives me 4508,4508 which is not what I intended.

```
x_w.shape
Out[85]: (4508, 1)

y_train.shape
Out[86]: (4508,)
```

Answer should (4508,) dimensions

Comment: Just do : `x_w[:,0]*y_train`.

Comment: or `np.squeeze(x_w)` or `x_w.ravel()` or `x_w[:, 0]` or `np.reshape(x_w, (-1,))` or `x_w.T` (this last one will result in shape (1, 4508))

Answer (score 0):

With shapes (4508, 1) and (4508,) the broadcasting goes as

```
(4508, 1) and (4508,) => (4508, 1) and (1, 4508) => (4508, 4508)
```

The key is that it can add a dimension at the start of `y` to match `x`, but you have give it permission to add it at the end.

To get (4508,) you need to remove that extra dim for `x`, before or after multiplication.

```
x[:,0], np.squeeze(x), x.reshape(-1)
```

or make `y` (4508,1), multiply, and squeeze.